# Redirecting all .html webpages to their .php equivalents?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Redirect *.htm to *.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610973/redirect-htm-to-php)
>   [htaccess rewrite if redirected file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437019/htaccess-rewrite-if-redirected-file-exists)

I set up a website a while ago and I had all the extensions as .html. I've learned a bit more about web development and would like to have everything as .php. The problem is that some of the pages have been bookmarked so I can't just change all the links and remove the .html files. I understand I could just add redirects on each page, but that would mean having two of each page on my site.

I'm wondering if there is a way using .htaccess to redirect any *.html to *.php if *.php exists.

Comment: @Michael, Alright, but how do I test if the php file exists? Not all of my pages with have their php version

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437019/htaccess-rewrite-if-redirected-file-exists which deals more exactly with your same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.html$ $1.php
```

or In your apache httpd.conf file you can add

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

Comment: 1) `AddType` is inappropriate; `AddHandler` should be used. 2) processing all files with an extension of "html" as PHP scripts doesn't address Walkerneo's issue and is wasteful.