# .htaccess point to php version of page if it exists

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've beens scratching my head trying to get this to work but I haven't be able to.

I need to redirect all html pages to php pages, all with the same name except the extension but only if the php version exists.

So if a page is "products.html" i need it to check if "products.php" exists, if it does, execute the php version (without redirecting the browser and showing products.php) if it doesn't, render the html version

Can this be done using htaccess? if so, could you help me with an example or point me to where i can find examples of this?

**Side Note:** I need to do this with both `.html` and `.htm` pages.

I also tried making html pages execute php code using the AddType and AddHandler examples i found online but none of them worked for me so that's why i decided to use php versions of each page instead.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: (OP's note) *"I need to do this with both `.html` and `.htm` pages."*

Comment: That's why I put in my comment above and edited your question to highlight the file extensions. @NeroFRox

Comment: BTW, this worked great for HTML pages but obviously it's not set up for htm as well, i'm going to try a few things and post back of if you know the answer for both that'd be great too.

Comment: Ok see edit now, it will take care of `.html` and `.htm` both.

Comment: `Another Happy Ending`

Answer (score -1):

You can set a rewrite rule to `index.php`, within the `index.php` file check if the file exist and serve it by using `include($page);`

```
$file = $_GET['page'];

if (file_exists($file)) {
    include($file);
} else {
    // 404 page...
}
```

Comment: Just to reiterate what I wrote in other comment that I didn't downvote this either.

Answer (score -2):

Your answer is solved here: [htaccess rewrite if redirected file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437019/htaccess-rewrite-if-redirected-file-exists)

The solution is a condition for your rewrite. It can be placed in the `.htaccess` of your root folder or just the folder where you want this feature.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (.*)\.html?$
RewriteCond %1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html?$ $1.php [P,L]
```

The only difference versus their answer is `P` as I have made your request an internal redirect to show the old URL to the user. Also, I use html? to get htm and html file.

This is described at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: @anubhava, no competitive downvoting please

Comment: (OP's note) *"I need to do this with both `.html` and `.htm` pages."* (btw, I did not downvote) ;-)

Comment: This is handled with the html?

Comment: @FullDecent: Just checked your comment and no I haven't downvoted you. As a matter of fact I very rarely downvote any answer.